# From tuple to 1d array

Tags: python

I have this list `[(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)]`
How can I convert it into 1d array `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: @Claudio: that looks a lot more like an answer than a request for information, a suggestion for an improvement to the question, or an aside.  Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @DSM my experience here is, that if the question is downvoted the answer will be downvoted too ... so what? Giving answer is bad for reputation, giving answer in a comment is also bad ... is someone downvoted for his question out of the game? By the way: the most probably right answer here is: a = array('l', [ item[0] for item in [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)] ] ) ...

Comment: @DSM am I right, that the purpose of downvoting a question is that no one should even read it? If I have put in the effort to read the question and have an answer at hand it cost me nearly nothing to leave the answer there ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test = [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)]
single = []

for i in test:
    single.append(i[0])

print(single)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack all the tuples:

```
>>> [e for e, in [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)]]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This is good, but I think a more generalized solution might be valuable `[e for t in [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)] for e in t]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That is flatten. This simply unpacks a list of 1-tuples into a list. It will error as it should if applied to a list of anything but 1-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)]
print([tup for tups in i for tup in tups])
```

output-

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

By 1D array, does the OP mean in the format of 1d numpy array?

If that is the case, then, it can be something as

```
tuple_ls=[(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)]
opt=np.array(tuple_ls).reshape(1,-1)
```

or

```
opt=np.array(tuple_ls).reshape(-1)
```

But, if it is just a typical list

```
list(sum([(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)], ()))
```